# Java stream with queue

Tags: java, queue, java-stream, rx-java, backpressure

I'm searching if it's possible to use Java stream with queue/backpressure.
Something like:

`iterator -> (queue?) -> parallelstream -> map -> collector`

Mapping is slower than iterator (even if multithreaded), so iterator should be read a slower pace (backpressure) or data from iterator should be queued to wait for mapping.
I've found that reactive stream can be used for backpressure (https://blog.softwaremill.com/how-not-to-use-reactive-streams-in-java-9-7a39ea9c2cb3) but what about a queue?

Comment: Java stream API isn't reactive. So it doesn't support backpressure. It's a lightweight feature to create a data manipulation streams in a functional style. Consider RxJava or Project Reactor instead.

Comment: Java 9 gained the [`Flow`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Flow.html) interfaces as a façade for [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) implementations. See [*JEP 266: More Concurrency Updates*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/266). These interfaces correspond to the [*reactive-streams* specification](http://www.reactive-streams.org/). [*Reactive Streams*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_Streams) is an initiative to provide a standard for asynchronous stream processing with non-blocking back pressure.

Comment: I've already sent a link to it, unfortunatelly it looks like this approach is still unfinished in java.
What abut a queue inside stream? Couldn't google for good example

Comment: Streaming an iterator should already have a form of backpressure because the on-demand (pull) nature of it. Is it necessary to have a queue between the iterator and the parallelStream? Do you have a more concrete example code about what you try to achieve?

Comment: If an iterator is of unknown size, parallel stream parallelize only every 1024 items - that's the problem